# Training data with complex vertices

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification

I am new to GEE. I built this script to conduct crop type mapping using RF. However, my training data contain too many vertices which I think is causing the problem of computation value and memory limit. I use the simplify function, I exported my inputProperties to asset but it seems that nothing is working. Any suggestions?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/18f2ce9d95ed351965f555e27b254e88

```js
// // //Generate  random pt sample
var random1 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Rice,
  points: 16000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});
var random2 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Maize,
  points: 20000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});

var random3 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: cotton,
  points: 14000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
})

var random4 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: potato,
  points: 14000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});
var random5 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: water,
  points: 5000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});
var random6 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Urban,
  points: 5000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});

var random7 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Wheat,
  points: 15000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
})


var referenceData = ee.Image().byte()
                  .paint(Rice, 0)
                  .paint(Maize, 1)
                  .paint(cotton,2)
                  .paint(potato,3)
                  .paint(water,4)
                  .paint(Urban,5)
                  .paint(Wheat,6)
                  .rename("class"); 

// // // // // // // Place the collections in a new collection.
//var combined = ee.FeatureCollection([random1,random2,random3,random4,random5,random6,random7]);
// Combine all of the random point feature collections into a single collection.
var flattened = ee.FeatureCollection([random1, random2, random3, random4, random5, random6, random7])
  .flatten(); //
//

// // // // // Flatten the collection to create a new collection with all the features.

//var flattened= random1.merge(random2).merge(random3).merge(random4).merge(random5).merge(random6).merge(random7);//;//.merge(random4)
// Simplify the geometries in the flattened collection.
var simplified = flattened.map(function(feature) {
  var simplifiedGeometry = feature.geometry().simplify(10000);
  return feature.setGeometry(simplifiedGeometry);
});

// // // Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = stacked.addBands(referenceData).reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection:simplified,//flattened,
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16
});


// //How balanced are the training data?
// //print(training.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["class"]));
 Map.addLayer(training,{},'training_sample',false);

// Filter out the null property values and try again.
var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(stacked.bandNames().add("class"))
)
var sample=trainingNoNulls.randomColumn();
var split=0.7
var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));
//print(training_sample,'training_sample')



var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(300)
  .train({
    features: training_sample,
    //.randomColumn().filter("random < 0.7"),
    classProperty: 'class',
    inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),//bands//
    
  })

var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified');

Map.addLayer(classified.randomVisualizer(),{},'classification', false);

// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
//print('Training producer accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
//print('Training Consumer accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.consumersAccuracy());


// // // // // //////////// validation sample//////

//Extract spectral data from the input image for validation points
var validation = stacked.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the point FeatureCollection.
  collection: validation_sample,
  // We'll classify on 'Level_2"
properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Sentinel-2 pixels at the points.
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 2
})

// Classify the validation data.
var validated = validation.classify(classifier);

// Get a confusion matrix representing expected accuracy.
var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('class', 'classification');
print('Test overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Test kappa accuracy: ', testAccuracy.kappa());
```